# Is it possible to collide "vertices" with a mesh?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I used cloth sim and trying to collide vertices with a mesh.
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the cloth simulation needs faces to interact with collision objects, so I don't think this is possible. But maybe someone else has an idea.

Comment: Sometimes answers depend on what you want to achieve. Why does it have to be just a line of vertices without a mesh? I mean, the resulting animation will not be visible in render without any faces, so what is it you are trying to do with it, maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You're right. I want lots of interacting cables on various surfaces. So i wished that if this line of vertices interacted with mesh then it won't be much heavy on my poor system and i can add shape to the line later as per my artistic choice. Doing it in one go will make my laptop burn.

Comment: The problem is, many of the settings in the cloth simulation depend on the geometry of the cloth, especially things like (self-)collision, stiffness and volume preservation. You could e.g. use a _Skin Modifier_ before the _Cloth Modifier_ to create some geometry, this will multiply the vertices "only" by 4. However, the cloth simulation then depends on the geometry created by the skin. No matter if you bake the simulation, disabling the _Skin Modifier_ (even if it's just in the viewport) afterwards will result in a weird messed up cloth geometry.